# Why do we need to install python modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, installation

Lets imagine I created new module. Why do I need to install it via setup file? I mean I can just add my module to PYTHONPATH variable and thats all. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For a simple one-file module, sure, that's enough.

But a `setup.py` file also lets you create a distribution, associate metadata with the distribution (author, homepage, description, etc.), register your package with the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) and most of all, lets you define what *other* packages might be needed to run your code. `setup.py` is not just for installing *your* module.

Installing a module with a `setup.py` based on `setuptools` also gives you additional functionality, such as support for namespaced packages (multiple distributions sharing a top-level name) and the ability to install multiple versions of a package side by side.